# Exclude nested component from children (Nuxt routing)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

is possible to exclude some nested components in pages directory from children of parent component? I need some nested components (`nested-a` and `nested-b`) render inside of parent component (`_id.vue`) and some nested components (standalone-nested) use as standalone pages which isn't rendered inside `_id.vue`, only use parent in route.

So my goal is to achieve these routes:

- `/account/{id}` - main page
- `/account/{id}/standalone-nested` - standalone page, not rendered inside parent
- `/account/{id}/nested-a` and `/account/{id}/nested-b` - nested components rendered inside parent

This is my directory tree:

```
pages
├── account
│   ├── _id
│   │   ├── nested-a.vue
│   │   ├── nested-b.vue
│   │   └── standalone.vue
│   ├── _id.vue
│   └── index.vue
└── index.vue
```

which generates following router:

```
{
    path: "/en/account/:id",
    component: _45553d28,
    name: "account-id___en",
    children: [{
      path: "nested-a",
      component: _7b67c342,
      name: "account-id-nested-a___en"
    }, {
      path: "nested-b",
      component: _7b75dac3,
      name: "account-id-nested-b___en"
    }, {
      path: "standalone",
      component: _6884b488,
      name: "account-id-standalone___en"
    }]
  }
```

in my parent component `_id.vue` I am using `<NuxtChild  />` to ensure rendering of nested components inside this component, but I don't know how to tell to nuxt which nested components render only inside this tag.

This is my MWE: https://github.com/DenisStephanov92/nuxt-routing-sample

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: can you share [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_working_example#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20minimal%20working,to%20be%20demonstrated%20and%20reproduced.&text=A%20minimal%20working%20example%20may,short%20self-contained%20correct%20example.)

Comment: @Chandan hi, thank you for effort, I added link to MWE on github

Comment: @DenisStephanov shouldn't this `_id.vue` be inside `_id` folder with name `id.vue`!!

Comment: @HardikShah no this cause removing all children from router

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem as you, although it's probably too late. But I'll leave this answer if anyone encounters a similar issue.

---

From your case, you wanted to make `standalone.vue` separated from parent `_id.vue`. But you want to still use the same sub-route as the other child.

You could actually use `extendRoutes` in `nuxt.config.js` to modify the generated route.
P.S: It's not necessary a clean way to do it though.

---

In `nuxt.config.js`, you can add `extendRoutes` to `router`, and modify them by using unshift and filter. Just like this

```
router: {
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.find(el => el.name === 'account-id___en')
      .children
      .filter(el => el.name !== 'account-id-standalone___en');
    routes.unshift({
      path: "/en/account/:id/standalone",
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/account/_id/standalone.vue'),
      name: "account-id-standalone___en"
    });
  },
},
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    path: "/en/account/:id/standalone",
    component: _6884b488,
    name: "account-id-standalone___en"
  },
  {
    path: "/en/account/:id",
    component: _45553d28,
    name: "account-id___en",
    children: [
      {
        path: "nested-a",
        component: _7b67c342,
        name: "account-id-nested-a___en"
      },
      {
        path: "nested-b",
        component: _7b75dac3,
        name: "account-id-nested-b___en"
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

Ref: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router/#extendroutes

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I quite get what you want to achieve but I did 2 buttons:

- **main page** button: conditionally rendering the `standalone` rather than the tabs, but still keeping the view into it's parent (path ends with `standalone-nested`)
- **real external** button: totally unrelated page, but which can still be accessed on the path that you wish, right now it's on `external-standalone-nested` but you can simply change it. For that, go to `external-standalone.vue` and change it in the `<router></router>` part.

All of this is doable thanks to the [`@nuxtjs/router-extras`](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) package.
I hope it helps you somehow. Of course, you could tinker it to have a specific layout for the standalone vs the non-standalone display.
You can of course move the `external-standalone.vue` file into the `account` directory too, if you want to have the `_id.vue` at the same level.

I hosted the solution on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-morse-i9sb2?file=/pages/account/_id.vue) and my commit - starting from your forked sample - can be found on [Github](https://github.com/kissu/nuxt-routing-sample/commit/9e287f437e757415508bede9d9fa13036cf9c8ec).

EDIT: I've commited again. Removed useless comments and added a [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components) example too as it's an interesting pattern that may help you *bypass* `nuxt-child` by something else.
Not exactly related to our use case but worth a look IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by manually extending the routes config, but I wrote a function to automate this for you. The way to use it is prepend the pages you want to be children with an `&` (these pages would be in the folder that has the same name as their parent). Any other page in these folders will be removed from the children and will be rendered without the parent. The function works recursively. You can change the prepend-symbold if needed. This version always keeps the `index` page in the folder as a child.

Some examples:

```
// parent1 > &child1 > parent2 > &child2 will render child1 inside parent1, not parent2 NOT in child1, child2 in parent2:
/parent1/child1/parent2
  /child2
/parent1
  /child1

// parent1 > &child1 > &parent2 > &child2 will render child1 inside parent1, parent2 in child1, and child2 in parent2:
/parent1
  /child1
    /parent2
      /child2
```

```js
const CHILD_CHAR = "&";
const URIENCODED_CHILD_CHAR = encodeURIComponent(CHILD_CHAR);

const removePathAmpersands = (path: string) => {
    return path.replace(new RegExp(`(^|\/)${URIENCODED_CHILD_CHAR}`, 'g'),  "$1");
}

const removeNameAmpersands = (name: string) => {
    return name.replace(new RegExp(`(^|-)${CHILD_CHAR}`, 'g'), "$1");
}

/**
 * When using nuxt-child, all sub-pages are by default rendered in the same parent.
 * This parser will recursively check if a child path starts with an `&`. If it does not, the route will not be a child.
 */
export const nuxtChildDepthParser = (routes: any[] = [], siblings?: any[], fullPath = "", parent?: any) => {
    const newSiblings = [] as typeof routes;

    let i = routes.length;
    while (i--) {
        const route = routes[i];
        nuxtChildDepthParser(route.children, newSiblings, fullPath + removePathAmpersands(route.path) + "/", route);
        if (!route.children?.length) delete route.children;

        if (fullPath) {
            if (route.path === `${URIENCODED_CHILD_CHAR}index`) {
                // The index route is a special case.
                // Its name must be set to the parent's name, parent's must be removed, and path must be empty
                route.name = parent.name;
                delete parent.name;
                route.path = "";
            } else {
                route.name = removeNameAmpersands(route.name);
                if (route.path.startsWith(URIENCODED_CHILD_CHAR)) {
                    route.path = removePathAmpersands(route.path);
                } else if (route.path !== "") {
                    // we should move this page up
                    route.path = fullPath + removePathAmpersands(route.path);
                    newSiblings.push(route);
                    routes.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    const parentSiblings = siblings ?? routes;
    parentSiblings.push(...newSiblings);
    parentSiblings.sort((a, b) => !a.children && b.children ? -1 : 1);
};
```

And then extend your router like so:

```js
router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, _resolve) {
        nuxtChildDepthParser(routes)
    }
},
```